# what is the significance of in the function calls that are given in msdn

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msdn

What is the significance of `_In_` the function calls that are given in msdn?

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
);
```

Comment: Please format the post and articulate a complete question in the body. The `In` is possibly a macro that resolves to nothing - used to semantically (read for better human understanding) mark an argument as input. When dealing with pointers it's not so easy to tell input parameters from output ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_In_`, `_Out_` and the like are [Microsoft SAL (source code annotation language) annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx)
for [Annotating Function Parameters and Return Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916382.aspx)

Microsoft's compilers can parse these annotations to detect possible
defects - a limited form of static analysis.

Answer (score 1):

As Margaret Bloom commented above, this is likely a macro that resolves to nothing to make it easier for the programmer to see that the variable is an input variable.

This is necessary because a lot of older windows functions take references to objects that are 'output' variables. I.E. you pass in a primitive/object pointer that the function makes changes to. This allows the function to return an int which can be used to store an error code.
As a side note, this^ is considered pretty bad practice these days and should be avoided. A function should return data via a normal return and all parameters should generally be considered input only.